# I can't retrieve supabase data with nextjs 14 and action servers

Tags: next.js, server, action, server-side-rendering, supabase

In my folder app/actionns/index.ts I have this

```
"use server";

import createSupabaseServerClient from "@/lib/supabase/server";

import { unstable_noStore as noStore, revalidatePath } from "next/cache";

export async function readTodo() {
   noStore();
   const supabse = await createSupabaseServerClient();
   return await supabse.from("posts").select("*");
}
```

But I can't get the data, in my console it returns null.

However, I checked the Supabase policies

In /app :

```
   const { data: todos } = await readTodo();
   console.log(todos); //return null
```

I would like to know how to display the data

Comment: Would you share the select policy on your `posts` table? Also, is the user signed in when you perform this query?